# Automatic way to write a JSON file to describe a ton of files?

Tags: arrays, json, automation

I come here with a question about a JSON.
Apparently, I must write a JSON file in which image files will be described.
It looks something like this:

```
"baseImagePath": "",
  "items": [
    {
      "sensorId": "7170",
      "gpsWeekSeconds": 130171.95161,
      "imagePath": "1/7170-62743.jpg",
      "x": 2618226.942,
      "y": 1152722.113,
      "z": 970.103,
      "rx": 1.50775449,
      "ry": 0.40420477,
      "rz": 0.0566376
    }
  ]
```

As you can see, I need every image to be written into "items", but the problem is that there are a **few thousand images**...
**MY QUESTION: Is there any automatic way to write those images without writing one by one?**
Obviously, I am not so familiar with JSON :(
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where do the image details come from? Do you have them already (maybe in a CSV?) or do you have a program that can generate them?

Comment: I have them already in a csv/txt file.

Comment: That's important information, it should be in the question (give a few lines of CSV as an example). Also you've not told which programming language you're using, that's pretty important as well.

Answer (score 0):

best way is probably pick a language (Python, Java, C++ etc.), find a JSON library for that language, write a script that does the writing for you, and run main().